# How to display free disk space in Lubuntu/LXDE?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, disk-usage, lxpanel, add-on

In Xubuntu/Xfce the xfpanel has an add-on for that (Free Space Checker).

Is there something similar for lxpanel or otherwise in LXDE/Lubuntu - or maybe a program with a similar service for all Ubuntu family or even for all Linux?

Comment: `df -h` if this is enough for you

Comment: @user827992 He is looking for a graphical panel on LXDE window manager not a command line tool.

Comment: @WilliamFleming the last part of his question is asking for something different :)

Comment: Also, not looking for something like Baobab - just a free space displaying gadget that I might see at all time. if that's not possible, df -h might just be the easiest way

Comment: well if you want a command line tool. Conky is a good system monitor tool.

Comment: @WilliamFleming can you tell me please how to shut it down after using it- ? :)

Comment: I usually just kill its task number. ps aux | grep conky Look for its pid number the kill xxxxx

Comment: Or `killall conky`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact a good answer to what I was asking here for --  something in LXDE/Lubuntu that would permanently display free space as Xfce does in the panel -- is coming from the file browser which always displays free space in the lower part of the window: it's true for PCMan, Nautilus and Thunar. So simple, but I don't think there's something better in Lubuntu.

In pcmanfm:

[image]

In Thunar:

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, but... what are you talking about exactly? Where does PCManFM display free space of a file system/disk?

Comment: @Bucic: i have edited the answer; in the posted images the system partition is the one involved, but it will do the same for any partition, including that of windows, external hdd and so on

Answer (score 9):

I prefer `Disk Usage Analyzer`

`sudo apt-get install baobab`

`baobab`

Answer (score 3):

Conky is the best doing that, here is a easy way to set up a awsome conky to your desktop http://browse.deviantart.com/?q=conky+colors#/d41qrmk